# Why is a request via my reverse proxy faster than a direct connection?

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx, latency

I have an ESP8266/ NodeMCU connected to my wifi which I used to make my fan a smart home device. It has a very simple HTTP server running, which allows me to send GET and POST request to get or change the current state, speed etc.

Additionally I have a nginx reverse proxy set up, that I use to connect to these devices (and other things). I've noticed that connecting directly to the ESP via its IP is slower (~`70ms`) than connecting via the reverse proxy (~`30ms`).

Chrome reports the following numbers:

Direct connection:

- ~`20ms` Waiting (TTFB)
- ~`45ms` Content Download

Via nginx:

- ~`30ms` Waiting (TTFB)
- ~`00ms` Content Download

If I understand it correctly nginx is able to send the request to the ESP, wait and download the content in about 30ms (which is reported to chrome in total as "Waiting"), while over the direct connection it takes close to 70ms. **How can this be?** I understand that content download is close to 0ms though, I have a 10G connection between my PC and the reverse proxy. The ESP is only connected over wifi which is not spectecularly fast, but the same for nginx <-> ESP and pc <-> ESP.

Also: I have noticed that if I try to connect via nginx a few seconds after connecting directly, it can take nginx up to 3s to reestablish the connection. This does not seem to happen though if I leave some more time in between both connections. **Is it that nginx somehow keeps the connection to the ESP open and therefore doesn't need to handshake** *(not sure if this is the correct term)* **everytime?**

Comment: Watch what happens in Wireshark/tcpdump. TCP window size would be my guess.

Comment: Perhaps nginx is caching and returns your last result, rather than getting a new one.

Comment: First thing to check would be whether the measurements are accurate and meaningful.  How are you making them?  +1 on the suggestion look at it in wireshark.

Comment: @harrymc It's definitely not caching. If I change the speed value (e.g. via a voice command), the next response does reflect the new value and takes ~30ms as well.

Comment: @user1686 I might try out Wireshark, though obviously as its not causing any trouble right it's not high up in my priorities and I never used the software.  Is TCP window size something similar to packet size?

Comment: @Duncan The results are from the chrome dev tools/ networking tab. I always thought those were trustworthy numbers :)

Comment: Are the network paths taken by the requests the same in both scenarios?